# InvalidClassException with Hibernate 3.6.0 and JPA 2.0

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've just started using hibernate 3.6.0 and JPA 2.0 and I'm having some troubles.

I get InvalidClassException on some queries. By the way I'm using metamodel with hibernate-jpamodelgen.

I.e. one below runs fine:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<UserEntity> cq = getCriteriaQuery(cb);
cq.where(cb.equal(cq.from(UserEntity.class).get(UserEntity_.username), username));
```

but with this one I'm having trouble:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<UserGroup> cq = getCriteriaQuery(cb);

cq.where(cb.equal(cq.from(UserGroup.class).join(UserGroup_.entries).join(UserGroupEntry_.user).get(UserEntity_.id), user.getId()));
```

I get exception like below.
All classes used in query implements Serializable.

I'm kinda lost here so any help would be appreciated.

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: com.ptm.model.BaseEntity; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 7662749495871325837, local class serialVersionUID = 8176072949097236524
     at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:579)
     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1600)
     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1513)
     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1600)
     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1513)
     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1749)
     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1346)
     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:368)
     at org.hibernate.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:244)
     at org.hibernate.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:306)
     at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:130)
     at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:116)
     at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:39)
     at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:62)
     at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)
     at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
     at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:249)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exception says that an object of class `BaseEntity` was stored in the database in serialized form and can't be deserialized because the class have been changed.

Storing objects in serialized form is a fallback strategy used by Hibernate when it can't figure out how object should be stored (i.e. it's not configured). Usually it's not a desired behaviour.

Perhaps in your case it means that one of the relationships between entities (`UserGroup_.entries` or `UserGroupEntry_.user`) is improperly configured.

Comment: There was some old data left. Data that was created when I used JPA 1.0 and older Hibernate version. When I removed that data from database it's all ok.